# PySpark; DecimalType multiplication precision loss

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When doing multiplication with PySpark, it seems PySpark is losing precision.

For example, when multiple two decimals with precision 38,10, it returns 38,6 and rounds to three decimals which is the incorrect result.

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([StructField("amount", DecimalType(38,10)), StructField("fx", DecimalType(38,10))])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(Decimal(233.00), Decimal(1.1403218880))], schema=schema)

df.printSchema()
df = df.withColumn("amount_usd", df.amount * df.fx)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Result

```py
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- amount: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- fx: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- amount_usd: decimal(38,6) (nullable = true)

>>> df = df.withColumn("amount_usd", df.amount * df.fx)
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- amount: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- fx: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- amount_usd: decimal(38,6) (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+--------------+------------+----------+
|        amount|          fx|amount_usd|
+--------------+------------+----------+
|233.0000000000|1.1403218880|265.695000|
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

Is this a bug? Is there a way to get the correct result?

Comment: Have you attempted to initialize the column with some value (i.e., `0` or `None`) and your desired `DecimalType`, then overwrite it with the desired values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is expected behavior.

Spark's Catalyst engine converts an expression written in an input language (e.g. Python) to Spark's internal Catalyst representation of that same type information. It then will operate on that internal representation.

If you check the file `sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/DecimalPrecision.scala` in [spark's source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0bfcf9c21069cabafc6fff47a801aa86ca13c608/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/DecimalPrecision.scala), it's used to:

> Calculates and propagates precision for fixed-precision decimals.

and

```
 * In particular, if we have expressions e1 and e2 with precision/scale p1/s2 and p2/s2
 * respectively, then the following operations have the following precision / scale:
 *   Operation    Result Precision                        Result Scale
 *   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   e1 * e2      p1 + p2 + 1                             s1 + s2
```

Now let's look at the code for multiplication. where a function `adjustPrecisionScale` is called:

```
    case Multiply(e1 @ DecimalType.Expression(p1, s1), e2 @ DecimalType.Expression(p2, s2)) =>
      val resultType = if (SQLConf.get.decimalOperationsAllowPrecisionLoss) {
        DecimalType.adjustPrecisionScale(p1 + p2 + 1, s1 + s2)
      } else {
        DecimalType.bounded(p1 + p2 + 1, s1 + s2)
      }
      val widerType = widerDecimalType(p1, s1, p2, s2)
      CheckOverflow(Multiply(promotePrecision(e1, widerType), promotePrecision(e2, widerType)),
        resultType, nullOnOverflow)
```

`adjustPrecisionScale` is where the magic happens, I pasted the [function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8258660f673f8b57a3cdd79ecd57c79df5554e31/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.scala) here so you can see the logic

```
  private[sql] def adjustPrecisionScale(precision: Int, scale: Int): DecimalType = {
    // Assumption:
    assert(precision >= scale)

    if (precision <= MAX_PRECISION) {
      // Adjustment only needed when we exceed max precision
      DecimalType(precision, scale)
    } else if (scale < 0) {
      // Decimal can have negative scale (SPARK-24468). In this case, we cannot allow a precision
      // loss since we would cause a loss of digits in the integer part.
      // In this case, we are likely to meet an overflow.
      DecimalType(MAX_PRECISION, scale)
    } else {
      // Precision/scale exceed maximum precision. Result must be adjusted to MAX_PRECISION.
      val intDigits = precision - scale
      // If original scale is less than MINIMUM_ADJUSTED_SCALE, use original scale value; otherwise
      // preserve at least MINIMUM_ADJUSTED_SCALE fractional digits
      val minScaleValue = Math.min(scale, MINIMUM_ADJUSTED_SCALE)
      // The resulting scale is the maximum between what is available without causing a loss of
      // digits for the integer part of the decimal and the minimum guaranteed scale, which is
      // computed above
      val adjustedScale = Math.max(MAX_PRECISION - intDigits, minScaleValue)

      DecimalType(MAX_PRECISION, adjustedScale)
    }
  }
```

Now let's walk through your example, we have

```
e1 = Decimal(233.00)
e2 = Decimal(1.1403218880)
```

each has `precision = 38`, `scale = 10`, so `p1=p2=38` and `s1=s2=10`. The product of these two shall have `precision = p1+p2+1 = 77`, and `scale = s1 + s2 = 20`

Note, the `MAX_PRECISION=38` and `MINIMUM_ADJUSTED_SCALE=6` here.

So `p1+p2+1=77 > 38`, 
`val intDigits = precision - scale = 77 - 20 = 57`
`minScaleValue = Math.min(scale, MINIMUM_ADJUSTED_SCALE) = min(20, 6) = 6`

`adjustedScale = Math.max(MAX_PRECISION - intDigits, minScaleValue) = max(38-57, 6)=6`

In the end, a DecimalType with `precision=38, and scale = 6` is returned. That's why you see the type for `amount_usd` is `decimal(38,6)`.

And in the `Multiply` function, both numbers have been converted to `DecimalType(38,6)` before doing the multiplication.

If you run your code with `Decimal(38,6)`, i.e.

```
schema = StructType([StructField("amount", DecimalType(38,6)), StructField("fx", DecimalType(38,6))])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(Decimal(233.00), Decimal(1.1403218880))], schema=schema)
```

You will get

```
+----------+--------+----------+
|amount    |fx      |amount_usd|
+----------+--------+----------+
|233.000000|1.140322|265.695026|
+----------+--------+----------+
```

Why the final number is `265.695000`? that might due to other adjustment in the `Multiply` function. But you get the idea.

From the `Multiply` code, you can see we want to avoid using maximum precision when doing multiplication, if we change to 18

```
schema = StructType([StructField("amount", DecimalType(18,10)), StructField("fx", DecimalType(18,10))])
```

We get this:

```
+--------------+------------+------------------------+
|amount        |fx          |amount_usd              |
+--------------+------------+------------------------+
|233.0000000000|1.1403218880|265.69499990400000000000|
+--------------+------------+------------------------+
```

we get a better approximation to the result computed by python:

```
265.6949999039999754657515041
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for giving detailed explanation with source code and running through example!